# What's the opposite of substr?

Tags: perl

I have a text file like so:

```
dave ran very quickly
dan very slowly ran
```

I am doing a regex to look for the word "ran" but I also need to know where it starts (in the first case it is character 6, in the second case it's 17).

I have (though it isn't much):

```
for(@lines){

if(/ran/){
 # find where ran is so we can continue parsing

}

}
```

Comment: The opposite of substr in Perl is the concatenation operator '.' .  Hint - pick a better question title.

Comment: The **opposite** of `substr` is, in fact, `substr` itself -- used as an l-value. The former plucks something out of a larger string; the latter jams something in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy:

```
my $ran_pos = $-[0];
```

See the `perlvar` man page for a detailed description of the `@-` array.

Comment: indeed, very easy. I feel ashamed.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the `index` function is what you're looking for.

Here are a couple links:

- http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/index_function.html
- http://www.misc-perl-info.com/perl-index.html

Comment: in some cases, you want the rarely mentioned rindex instead

Answer (score 2):

index STR,SUBSTR will return the position of a substring within a string.